Google Apps Scripts in Google Sheets, click outside ui.prompt pop up window caused timeout error without any return value
When using Apps Script to extend functionality in my spread sheet, I need to load a value provided by a user. However, when pop-up window is initiated via:
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Instruction:',
      'Another instruction',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

and user clicked outside of the pop-up window (so no "OK" or "Cancel" button clicked), immediately there is a message indicating en error with the code execution and the code is stuck on a timeout. When trying to catch the error
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  try {
      var result = ui.prompt(
          'Instruction:',
          'Another instruction',
          ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error occurred');  // <--- THIS LINE
    return;
  }

Logger.log('The code is still running'); // <--- NOR THIS LINE

no message is logged.
So there is no change to read result.getSelectedButton() as the execution is terminated with the ui.promt line.
My code runs outside Google Workspace environment, so some functionality is limited, for example like using showModalDialog() Errors when clicking outside an alert window.
How can I somehow read the status of "clicked outside of the window" or catch an exception immediately? Or is there some reasonable workaround for this?
P.S: I am trying to load some unique ID provided by a user in order to save his "vote". Initially I intended to use Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); but functionality of obtaining user's email even for invited users with edit rights inside onEdit() function is limited too.

I think that there is a misconception here.
When a script uses a dialog using an alert or prompt while the execution is waiting for a user action, the execution time is not paused, so if the user takes too much time to click a button or to close the dialog, the execution time exceeded error will occur.
To avoid this from happening, you might use a custom dialog using the HTML Service, for further details, read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs.

Thanks for the answer. I have tried to use HTML Service, however for this reason the user must approve additional permissions as a separate application (which will display a message that the application is not verified...I would like to avoid this process of registering and approving the app). Not speaking about the fact that none of this, HTML nor Pop-up windows does not work when using mobile app. I try to make the user have as little work as possible, I have to force him to use the desktop version anyway.

And about the link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs: "Alerts suspend the server-side script while the dialog is open. The script resumes after the user closes the dialog", that's the thing that resuming will never happen when clicking outside of the pop-up window. Probably I should report this as an issue.
